# pysaml2 microsoft entra ID Failure reason: KEY-NOT-FOUND Error: failed to verify file

Tags: python, azure, saml, saml-2.0

I have created and enterprise application in azure portal and did the setup as below[image]

And below is my code in python

```
acs_url = 'http://localhost:8000/user/login/sso/auth'

    rv = requests.get("App Federation Metadata Url From Azure Dashboard")
    # I have to do this because
    # the "inline" metadata type isn't working in PySAML2
    import tempfile
    tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    f = open(tmp.name, 'w')
    f.write(rv.text)
    f.close()
    
    settings = {
        'metadata': {
            "local": [tmp.name]
            },
        'entityid': 'http://localhost:8000/user/login/sso/auth',
        'service': {
            'sp': {
                'endpoints': {
                    'assertion_consumer_service': [
                        (acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                        (acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_POST)
                    ],
                },
                # Don't verify that the incoming requests originate from us via
                # the built-in cache for authn request ids in pysaml2
                'allow_unsolicited': True,
                # Don't sign authn requests
                'authn_requests_signed': False,
                'want_assertions_signed': True,
                'want_response_signed': False,
            },
        },
        'debug': 1,
        "logging": {
            "version": 1,
            "formatters": {
                "simple": {
                    "format": "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s.%(funcName)s] %(message)s",
                },
            },
            "handlers": {
                "stdout": {
                    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                    "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
                    "level": "DEBUG",
                    "formatter": "simple",
                },
            },
            "loggers": {
                "saml2": {
                    "level": "DEBUG"
                },
            },
            "root": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "handlers": [
                    "stdout",
                ],
            },
        },
    }
    
    spConfig = Saml2Config()
    spConfig.load(settings)
    spConfig.allow_unknown_attributes = True
    saml_client = Saml2Client(config=spConfig)
    tmp.close()
    authn_response = saml_client.parse_authn_request_response(
        SAMLResponse,
        entity.BINDING_HTTP_POST)
    authn_response.get_identity()
    user_info = authn_response.get_subject()
    # username = user_info.text

    
    print(user_info)
```

And I am getting this error

error=Verification status: FAILED

Failure reason: KEY-NOT-FOUND

Error: failed to verify file "/var/folders/60/1yz0pnwd2jv15p28bffgz8p40000gn/T/tmpza0_h534.xml"

I have gone through a lot of docs and answers on SO but none is helping. I hope someone can provide some light to this problem.

Thank you